# Alamofire: how to append a json array parameter in a multipart form data?

Tags: ios, alamofire, multipartform-data

I'm tryna send a photo along with parameters, but the catch is that I want to send a JSON array to the server. It seems Alamofire doesn't have a method to send a list of `Data`, so what's another good alternative to this?

the key part of the problem is:

```
var encodedTags: [Data] = tags.map({ return $0.data(using: .utf8)!})
            mpd.append(encodedTags, withName: key)
```

within this upload call:

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["username": "TheCooliest", ..., "tags": ["KoolKid", "TheKooliest", "BetterThanKimK"]    
...

upload(multipartFormData: { (mpd) in
        mpd.append(url, withName: "file", fileName: "weeknd.jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let tags = value as? [String], key == "tags" {
                var encodedTags = tags.map({ return $0.data(using: .utf8)!})
                mpd.append(encodedTags, withName: key)

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I used `JSONSerialization`. It converts my list into an `Any` object which I convert into Data.

```
for (key, value) in parameters {
    if let tags = value as? [String], key == "tags" {

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: tags, options: .prettyPrinted)
            mpd.append(json as Data, withName: key)
        } catch {}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that with Swift 4, you could use the new JSONEncoder.
You could do something like this to upload a file and a JSON parameter using multipart form data:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "test")
let png = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!

let arr = ["str1", "str2"]
let jsonArr = try? JSONEncoder().encode(arr)

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiPart) in
    multiPart.append(png, withName: "file", fileName: "aaa.png", mimeType: "image/png")

    if let jsonArr = jsonArr {
        multiPart.append(jsonArr, withName: "pictures")
    }
}, to: URL) { (result) in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same situation, you have to convert your array to string then encode and upload.
 In my case i had to encrypt the array and send to server then server decrypts the array.

```
var encodedTags = tags.map({ return $0})
 //write logic to convert array to string
 mpd.append(encodedTags.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the Answer for Multipart request, Please review code.**

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
        let firstNameTxt = self.firstNmae.text!.data(using: .utf8)
        multipartFormData.append(firstNameTxt!, withName: "first_name", mimeType: "text/plain")
    },
                     usingThreshold:UInt64.init(), to:AppConstant.GlobalConstants.updateProfile, method:.post, headers:["Authorization": "auth_token"],encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                debugPrint(response)
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                        }
    })
```